# send push notification with vue-native and expo

Tags: vue.js, expo, vue-native

I'm new to vue-native and vuejs and want to make an application with them. I want to add push notification to the app. I use [this](https://vue-native.io/docs/device-apis.html#Register-device-with-Expo-and-store-the-token) tutorial for add push notification and test it but I get this Error

> Error in created hook: "TypeError:
>   this.registerForPushNotificationsAsync is not a function. (In
>   'this.registerForPushNotificationsAsync()',
>   'this.registerForPushNotificationsAsync' is undefined)"

I add this block of code in my project like this in app.vue file

```
    <template>
    <view class="container">
        <text class="text-color-primary">{{JSON.stringify(notification.data)}}</text>
    </view>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data: function() {
      return {
        notification: {}
      };
    },
    created: function() {
       this.registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
       this._notificationSubscription = Notifications.addListener(
         this._handleNotification
       );
     },

     methods:{
       _handleNotification: function(notification) {
         this.notification = notification;
       },
       registerForPushNotifications: async function() {
         const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
           Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
         );
         let finalStatus = existingStatus;

         // only ask if permissions have not already been determined, because
         // iOS won't necessarily prompt the user a second time.
         if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
           // Android remote notification permissions are granted during the app
           // install, so this will only ask on iOS
           const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(
             Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
           );
           finalStatus = status;
         }

         // Stop here if the user did not grant permissions
         if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
           return;
         }

         // Get the token that uniquely identifies this device
         Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync().then(token => {
           console.log(token);
         });
       }
     }
};



</script>
```

where i go wrong?

Comment: try this `created: function() { this.registerForPushNotifications()}`

Comment: if it didn't work then you probably didn't install vue-native properly or your app didn't recognize it, because the function you got the error from is the first vue-native code on your app